# Google apps script UiApp does not center elements in Internet Explorer

Tags: google-apps-script

I have panels in my web app, and I am setting style attributes like so:

```
panel.setStyleAttribute('margin-left', 'auto').setStyleAttribute('margin-right','auto');
```

This wors perfectly in chrome, centering the element as expected. However in IE, the elements are stuck to the left of the screen.

Is there any way around this issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike other browsers, margin:auto only works in Internet Explorer if you force standards mode rather than quirks mode.

UiApp defaults to quirks mode CSS rules, unless (a) you load a GuiBuilder component in the initial app creation, which forces standards mode, or (b) you explicitly ask for standards mode.

This will set you in standards mode and therefore work in IE too:

```
function doGet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setStandardsMode(true);
  return app.add(app.createLabel('centered').setStyleAttributes(
      {marginLeft: 'auto',
       marginRight: 'auto',
       width: '100px'}));
}
```

Note the **setStandardsMode(true)** - without this it won't work in IE. Be careful though because standards mode styles are interpreted differently sometimes than quirks mode, so this might change other aspects of your layout.

Some notes:

- setStandardsMode is only respected on initial app creation (i.e., in doGet) and is ignored if you try to set it in a handler later.
- the GuiBuilder's layout rules assume standards mode, which is why that implicitly forces standards mode. If you load a GuiBuilder component in a callback in an app that was not set to standards mode during doGet (either explicitly or because you loaded another component) there might be subtle changes to the layout and styles due to it being in quirks mode.

Comment: Thanks Corey. Unfortunately, as you pointed out, the site isn't styled as I would expect in IE when in standards mode. I'm going to have to re write using a standard LAMP server. thanks

Comment: I'd really recommend using standards mode even on your own LAMP... quirks mode is, as you can see, completely unpredictable browser-to-browser. You'll have this problem in IE regardless of what server platform you are using. It's worth learning how standards mode CSS works and resetting your expectations to match that (whether in Apps Script or elsewhere) because there's no other good way to get consistent results.

Comment: Many thanks for the advice Corey - i'm relatively new to web programming so I definitely need to familiarise myself with these concepts.

Comment: @Corey ; is that usage of standard mode vs quirks mode mentioned in the documentation somewhere ? (if not could you recommend any reference info on this ? (it's beyond my personal knowledge but I love to learn ;-)

Comment: For the record, UiApp is in quirks mode because when we launched it it  was necessary and at this point we don't want to break it on people whose CSS would be suddenly changed. HtmlService is all standards mode, all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Use normalized forms for CSS style attributes

```
panel..setStyleAttribute('marginLeft', 'auto').setStyleAttribute('marginRight','auto')
```

You may check a list of supported style attributes [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/ui_supportedStyles)

Comment: Unfortunately, the issue still remains - all elements are centred in chrome but to the left in IE .. any further thoughts ?

Comment: Yeah, I too noticed this. Please report this issue in Issue tracker. http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list

Answer (score 0):

I have logged issue #2159 with google for this issue.

http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2159